# Break And Continue Statement in nested loops

Tags: python, nested-loops, break, continue

So i was experimenting the for-loop in Python and i decided let me use continue and break statements for experimentation and i got to know what's the difference. So "break" exits your loop completely and "continue" skips the current iteration of the loop and continues it but the headache started when i experimented with the "break" and "continue" in nested loops and i see no difference in the code which i have pasted below

1.)"break" nested loop.

```
for i in range(6):
    print("iteration {}".format(i))
    for j in range(6):
        if i == 3:
            break
        print(j)
```

2.) "continue" nested loop

```
for i in range(6):
    print("iteration {}".format(i))
    for j in range(6):
        if i == 3:
            continue
        print(j)
```

And my question is why does "continue" and "break" act the same in nested-loops in my code???

for those who are wondering Outputs for the loops

1.)for "break"

```
   iteration 0
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 1
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 2
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 3
iteration 4
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 5
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

2.)Output for "continue"

```
iteration 0
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 1
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 2
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 3
iteration 4
0
1
2
3
4
5
iteration 5
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Would be great help for the answer!!...thanksss..

Comment: I see no nested loops.

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Looping and breaking immediately exhibits similar output to looping all the way through and not doing anything every time. Even though the loop is run a different number of times, it doesn't affect what output you get from this code. Which one did you expect to do something different, and why?

Comment: i fixed the indentation too and can you please check the code...i still cannot figure out the difference between 'continue' and 'break' in nested loops and check the above code and run it and see if you find a difference

Comment: The two inner loops do behave differently, but that difference is not externally visible.  The first loop breaks on the first iteration when `i` is `3`, printing nothing.  The second skips the loop body when `i` is `3`, moving to the next iteration of the inner loop until `j` reaches the end of the range.  Since both loops print nothing in that case, they appear to behave identically, even though the first loop exits immediately while the second continues running but skips the loop body.

Comment: If you want to see the difference, add a `print` call to the top of the inner loop, saying something like "looping on j".  The first loop will print it once, while the second will print it 6 times (when `i` is `3` in both cases).

Answer (score 2):

*The `break` version:*

When `i == 3` the `break` breaks out of the `j`-loop at the *first* iteration so it does nothing.

*The `continue` version:*

When `i == 3` the `continue` goes back to the top of the `j`-loop before the `print()` call on *every* iteration so the `print()` call doesn't happen.